# Передача двумерного динамического массива в функцию

Tags: c++, массивы, функции, указатели, динамические-массивы

Функция должна возвращать количество отрицательных элементов динамического массива.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

const int N = 5;
const int M = 5;

int** s;
void Fill(int a, int b, int **s)
{
    s = new int* [a];
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        s[i] = new int[b];

    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
        {
            s[i][j] = rand() % 10 - 5;
            cout << s[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
int Sort(int **Arr)
{
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
            if (*(Arr+i*M+j) < 0)
                k++;
    }
    return k;
}
int main()
{
    Fill(N, M, s);
    cout << endl;
    cout << Sort(s)<<endl;;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

В функции Sort вылетает исключение из-за которого программа не работает корректно.
Вопрос: как обращаться к элементам динамического массива, переданного в функцию?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну вы же уже решили, что ваш двумерный массив - это массив указателей на строки! А дальше начинаете обращаться к нему, как к обычному статическому двумерному массиву из одного блока памяти! `*(Arr+i*M+j)` в этом контексте категорически неверно! `Arr[i][j]` - вот так надо обращаться к его элементам.

И еще - в `Fill` вы размеры массива передаете, а в `Sort` - нет. "Как-то неаккуратненько" (с) Анекдот...